# How can i plot multiple graphs as subplot?

Tags: python, loops, subplot

I have 5 graphs. My code continue with this way:

```
plots = zip(x,y)
def loop_plot(plots):
    figs = {}
    axs = {}
    for idx, plot in enumerate(plots):
        figs[idx] = plt.figure()
        axs[idx] = figs[idx].add_subplot(111)
        axs[idx].plot(plot[0],plot[1])
    return figs, axs

figs,axs=loop_plot(plots)
```

This code create 5 different graph. BUt I would like to plot 5 graph in one figure. I mean, I would like to create 5 different figure into one code. How can I manage it? I have 5 different x and y dataset. how can I write subplot code with for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about using the terms `figure` and `axes` when talking about matplotlib, as they mean slightly different things to normal English usage. An `axes` object is a pair of (x,y) axes, and a `figure` is a container that holds one or more `axes`. The reason I say that is because the code to solve your problem will be different if you want five different lines on one set of axes, or if you want one figure containing 5 separate axis, each with one line.

## 5 separate axes

```
def loop_plot1(plots):
    shape = (2, 3) # Fix this to make it more general if you want to handle more than 6 plots!
    list_ax = []
    fig = plt.figure()
    for i, plot in enumerate(plots):
        idx = i + 1
        list_ax.append(fig.add_subplot(shape[0], shape[1], idx)) # a more general way of writing, eg, add_subplot(231) etc.
        list_ax[i].plot(plot[0], plot[1])
loop_plot1(plots)
```

[image]

## 5 lines on one axes

```
def loop_plot2(plots):
    shape = (2, 3) # Fix this to make it more general if you want to handle more than 6 plots!
    fig, ax = plt.subplots() # implicitly does fig = plot.figure() // fig.add_subplot(111)
    for i, plot in enumerate(plots):
        ax.plot(plot[0], plot[1])
loop_plot2(plots)
```

[image]